# Angular: add a component inside an innerHTML

Tags: angular, components, code-injection

I would like to inject a component through an innerHTML.

```
  <article class="card-body">
    <div class="body-container" [innerHTML]="bodyCard.content"></div>
  </article>
```

```
  @Input() bodyCard: BodyCard = {
    content: `
    <p class="body-content">
     some text
     // then the component
    <ftn-tooltip></ftn-tooltip>
    </p>
```

I have no error but the component does not display. I checked with ComponentFactoryResolver but it seems to work only with ng-template and not with a HTML tag such as a DIV.

Any reccomendation please ?

Comment: Look at web components

Comment: can you give more details please

Comment: You can't do it simply by changing `innerHTML` you have to create a component dynamically and inject it - or better yet, simply use an `*ngIf` and put it in your template instead of mixing HTML into your TS file

Comment: the main purpose is to have a component that can inject the ftn-tooltip many times at different place. So *ngIf is not appropriate

Comment: I bet it is appropriate, and even easy. If you can provide more details in your question about what the content to be injected can look like I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can inject a component using [componentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader)

A directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[adHost]',
})
export class AdDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Allow get the "ViewContainerRef" of a ng-template or div. adding in a html tag

```
<ng-template adHost></ng-template>
```

Then we can get the "ng-template" and his ViewContainerRef using ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: true}) adHost!: AdDirective;
```

And in any moment use like

```
//get the component -see that we put the Class of component
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);

//see we get the viewContainerRef of the "directive"
const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
viewContainerRef.clear();

const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<MyComponent>(componentFactory);
```

Some authores, like [Dave Rivera](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286) prefer to have a service. It's the same idea but its a bit transparent because all the responsability of create the component is translatate to the service

```
export class LoaderService {  
  viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private factoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  } 
  
  setViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef) {
    this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef
  }  
  
  addHelloComponent() {
    const factory = this.factoryResolver
                        .resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent)

    this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    
    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent<HelloComponent>(factory);
    return componentRef.instance;
  }}
```

Now, we can inject the service, call the function AddHelloComponent passing a ViewContainerRef in any moment if we has a constructor

```
constructor(private loaderService:LoaderService){}

//and in any moment
this.loaderService.addHelloComponent(this.adHost.viewContainerRef);
```

we can join the two concepts and create a directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[adHello]',
})
export class AdHelloDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('adHello') name
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,private factoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
  ngOnInit(){
    const factory = this.factoryResolver
    .resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent)

this.viewContainerRef.clear();

const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent<HelloComponent>(factory);
 componentRef.instance.name=this.name;

  }
}
```

that it's used like

```
<ng-template adHello="new from adhelo"></ng-template>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ik8jmw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thanks for your respond but with this approach I cannot still inject the component into the innerHTML. 
The way to do that is to use the ngx-dynamic-hooks librabry. Here is its main purpose :
 Automatically insert live Angular components into dynamic strings (based on their selector or any pattern of your choice) and render the result in the DOM.
https://github.com/MTobisch/ngx-dynamic-hooks