# How to show a dynamically inserted fontawesome icon in template through innerHTML?

Tags: angular, angular-fontawesome

I am looking for a way to display text (markdown) on page that can contain a fontawesome icon. The framework is Angular 15 and fortawesome 6 has been used.

The text is dynamically inserted through an `innerHTML` tag.
Through a markdown pipe I was able to convert the text (in markdown) to semantically correct HTML. Unfortunately, regarding the parse of the icons, I have not found a good solution for the moment. What I don't understand is, how do I prevent `ng/security#xss` from cleaning up my code and simultaneously have the icon placeholder convert to call the fontawesome component and display it?

I tried using

```
content.replace(/{!!icon!!}/g, '<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>')
```

to replace the placeholder `{!!icon!!}` with the icon. However, Angular's security intervenes and kills the `<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>`. So I attempted to use `return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml` in pipe to prevent the `ng/security#xss` from killing my code. This works but the icon is not displayed because the code `<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>` is not interpreted.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizer'
})
export class SanitizerPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(content: string, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
      return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.iconParser(content)) as SafeHtml;
    }
  }

  private iconParser = (content: string) => {
    return content.replace(/{!!icon!!}/g, `<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>`);
  }

}
```

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769890/angular-add-a-component-inside-an-innerhtml) asked quite some time ago they had solved by injecting the fontawesome component. So my approach is easily wrong, however I have no idea how I could solve it with this.

Angular's unnecessarily complicated "documentation"(API), says nothing on this topic, as usual.

Comment: See [docs](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/guide/advanced-uses.md).

Comment: +1 @YaroslavAdmin you are right! The solution is in the guide you linked. If you generate a complete answer I will accept it as the most accurate one. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to add an answer yourself and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular problem is solved directly by Fontawesome through [this guide](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/guide/advanced-uses.md). The library (angular-fontawesome) provides the function [`icon()`](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/apis/javascript/methods#icon-icondefinition-params). This solves the problem as you just need to do:

```
import { icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

...

private iconParser = (content: string) => {
  return content.replace(/{!!icon!!}/g, `${icon(faCoffee).html.join('')}`);
}
```

The `icon(faCoffee).html.join('')` code generates a valid SVG:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" ... ><path fill="currentColor" ...></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Content rendered inside `innerHTML` exists outside the angular context, so `fa-icon` component does not exist! that is why you are getting this issue. Generally, content inside `innerHTML` should not contain any angular functionality. Since you just want to render a font, you can use the original font awesome html to do this.

```
<i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

in the pipe it will be

```
private iconParser = (content: string) => {
    return content.replace(/{!!icon!!}/g, `<i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>`);
  }
```

Comment: This solution works but is not entirely accessible: the <i> tag that generates through CSS the icon. Instead, the answer I prefer is the one that is mentioned in the guide linked by @YaroslavAdmin ([link](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/guide/advanced-uses.md))

Comment: @Visibly0467 ok glad its fixed!